# Monotonicity of function involving ratios of modified Bessel function of first kind

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions, approximation-theory

I am a scientist who is trying to come up with some analytic solutions for a system that I only have approximate answers to and I have run into the problem of proving that the following function is monotone.

$$\sqrt{\lambda} \left[ \frac{I_0(2\sqrt{\lambda})}{I_1(2\sqrt{\lambda})} - \frac{I_1(2\sqrt{\lambda})}{I_0(2\sqrt{\lambda})} \right].$$

Where $I_n(x)$ is modified Bessel function of the first kind.

I am honestly not sure where to begin and any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As Robert Israel's answer says, we can reduce this to proving the inequality
$$ x( I_1(x)^4 - I_0(x)^4) + 2 I_0(x)^3 I_1(x) < 0 ; $$
a more useful form for our purposes is
$$ 1 - \left( \frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)} \right)^4 - \frac{2}{x} \frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)} > 0 . $$
It suffices to find a simple upper bound for the ratio, then verify it satisfies the inequality. The easiest way we are aware of follows Nåsell (1979), [Rational bounds for ratios of modified Bessel functions](https://doi.org/10.1137/0509001), *SIAM J. Math. Anal.*, Vol. 9, No. 1. (N.B. in this paper $(x)_k$ is the rising factorial and $[x]$ is the largest integer not larger than $x$, i.e. the floor of $x$.)

The idea is to use the recurrence relations
$$ I_{\nu-1}(x) - I_{\nu+1}(x) = \frac{2\nu}{x} I_{\nu}(x) \\
 I_{\nu-1}(x) + I_{\nu+1}(x) = 2I_{\nu}'(x) $$
repeatedly, to write derivatives of the expression $ g_{\nu}(x) = x^{-\nu} e^{-x} I_{\nu}(x) $ in terms of $I_{\nu}$ and $I_{\nu+1}$, and then use that $ (-1)^k g_{\nu}^{(k)}(x) $ is positive for $x>0$ and $\nu>-1$) (Nåsell does this by using that $g_{\nu}$ is the Laplace transform of a positive function); this expression can then be rearranged to find rational bounds for the ratio.

For example, we have
$$ \begin{align}
-g_{\nu}'(x) &= \nu x^{-\nu-1} e^{-x} I_{\nu}(x) + x^{-\nu} e^{-x} I_{\nu}(x) - x^{-\nu} e^{-x} I_{\nu}'(x) \\
&= x^{-\nu} e^{-x} \left( \left(\frac{\nu}{x}+1\right) I_{\nu} + \frac{\nu}{x} I_{\nu}(x) - I_{\nu-1}(x) \right) \\
&= x^{-\nu} e^{-x} \left( \left(\frac{2\nu}{x}+1\right) I_{\nu} - I_{\nu-1}(x) \right) ; 
\end{align}$$
so
$$ \frac{2\nu+x}{x} I_{\nu} - I_{\nu-1}(x) > 0 , $$
or changing the index,
$$ \frac{I_{\nu+1}(x)}{I_{\nu}(x)} > \frac{x}{2(\nu+1)+x} . $$

**EDIT:** the previous bound was not good enough since I made a calculation error. The idea still works, but is sadly rather more complicated that I originally hoped.

The bound Nåsell calls $U_{0,5,0}$ turns out to be sufficent, but easier to see is
$$ \frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)} < U_{0,6,0} = \frac{ 2x(30 + 36 x + 27 x^2 + 16 x^3 + 16 x^4) }{ 120 + 144 x + 123 x^2 + 82 x^3 + 48 x^4 + 32 x^5 }, $$
which gives
$$ \begin{align}
&1 - \left( \frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)} \right)^4 - \frac{2}{x} \frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)}  \\
&> \frac{x^2}{(120 + 144 x + 123 x^2 + 82 x^3 + 48 x^4 + 
  32 x^5)^4} \\
&\quad \times (25920000 + 124416000 x + 263044800 x^2 + 412784640 x^3 + 538137432 x^4 + 620215488 x^5 \\
&\qquad + 627520365 x^6 + 542714256 x^7 + 421454952 x^8 + 293542656 x^9 + 178465536 x^{10} \\
&\qquad + 92432384 x^{11} + 40183808 x^{12} + 16711680 x^{13} + 3670016 x^{14} + 524288 x^{15}), \end{align} $$
which is clearly positive since every coefficient is.

Comment: I think you made a mistake when you converted Robert Israel's expression into the one with ratios.

Comment: Working with what I think you wanted to do, which is dividing throughout by $I_0(x)^4$, the bounds don't work out the way you'd want them to.

Comment: Looks like, with the corrected expression, it is, in fact, always less than zero instead of being more than zero.

Comment: @AnalyticPotato You're quite right, I made a rather significant transcription error. I've corrected the answer; the method does still work, but the rational function involved is unfortunately rather further up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but may be helpful as a start.

First of all, we might as well define $x = 2 \sqrt{\lambda}$.  Then with $g(x) = I_0(x)/I_1(x)$, you want $x (g(x) - 1/g(x))$ to be monotone (decreasing) for $x > 0$.
This turns out to be equivalent to
$$  -  {{ I}_{0}\left(x\right)} ^{4}x+  {{ I}_{1
}\left(x\right)} ^{4}x+2\,  {{ I}_{0}\left(x\right)}
  ^{3}{{ I}_{1}\left(x\right)} < 0
$$

It's certainly true when $x$ is small and when $x$ is large (by using the first couple of terms of the known Maclaurin series and asymptotics of $I_0$ and $I_1$).  With some effort it should be possible to translate those into explicit bounds: say $0 < x < \epsilon$ and $x > N$.  That leaves a finite interval: by careful numerical evaluation at a finite number of points, plus bounds on derivatives, it should be possible to cover this interval by subintervals on which the inequality is true.